# How to concatenate along multiple axes in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I have two tensors with the shapes:

```
tensor_a = (None,3,3,64)

tensor_b = (None,1,1,64)
```

I'm using `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()` layer to concatenate those two tensors. And I pass the axis argument with different values. But I get the error of mismatched shapes. Can I cocatenate along 1st and 2nd axes at the same time?
Here is the error I get:

```
A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis.
```